# Android Activity Manager killing app if in background longer then 60 sec

Tags: android

In API level 19 if the application is put to background the android os keeps it running, but in API  level 21 after 60 sec it kills it. This is what i see in the logcat:09-28 23:16:14.268     841-1582/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 9326:com.myapp/u0a298 (adj 7): kill background.
Is there a way (some flag) to tell the os not to terminate/kill?

Comment: No way of doing that without having a service which is in foreground.

Comment: Thx. That works fine